# Write data to CSV from two ArrayList

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I need to write my data inside two arraylist into these format of CSV file

```
Domain         Total
gmail.com      90

Application     Total
IP 1             30
IP 2             30
IP 3             30
```

the first arraylist will store the data for domain and total which will look like the following. The sequence of the data in the arraylist is `Total`,`Domain`

```
[2212, gmail.com"]
```

the second arraylist will store the data for application and total which will look like the following.The sequence of the data in the arraylist is `IP`,`Total`

```
["192.168.0.175", 403, "192.168.0.26", 1809]
```

I am looking a best way for write my data into the csv file but I cant really understand how it's work? Can anybody provide any direction, I am lost in this part now

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Are you using csvWriter?

Comment: Missing a quote mark with gmail.com example?

Comment: I tried read the example online but I am getting lost now

Comment: csvWriter will be a good option ?

Comment: Are you trying to write both kinds of data into same file? Why are you asking about two scenarios? Have you searched Stack Overflow? Many Java + CSV Questions have already been asked and answered. Explain how your Question is different and not already covered.

Comment: I searched over the stackoverflow, there's contain many method. That why make me a bit lost now. All the data will wrote into one file with a proper header plus data

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use any external library for writing into CSV file. They are just `txt` file separated by comma.

Here is the code which will do the job :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
class test
{
    public static void main(String arg[])throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("2212");
        list1.add("gmail.com");

        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add("192.168.0.175");
        list2.add("403");
        list2.add("192.168.0.26");
        list2.add("1809");

        File file = new File("test.csv");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write("Domain,Total");
        bw.newLine();
        for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
        {
            bw.write(list1.get(i+1)+","+list1.get(i++));
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.write("\nApplication,Total");
        bw.newLine();
        for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
        {
            bw.write(list2.get(i++)+","+list2.get(i));
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: While not necessary, a library such as [*Apache Commons CSV*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) does make it less of a chore.